# Get APNS token in electron (for FCM)

Tags: push-notification, electron, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I want to implement push notifications in my desktop app, the backend uses Firebase to send notifications to all types of devices.

I want to:

- get the APNS token of the device.
- convert it to FCM token.
- send the FCM token to the backend (subscribe).

I already found out how to convert APNS tokens to registration tokens from [this google docs page](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#results_4)
I am assuming that the registration token is the FCM and correct me if I am wrong.

But I am still unable to make the first step which is to get the APNS token itself.

What I need is basically the `registerForRemoteNotifications` function. but in electron

Comment: Did you see this link? https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/push-notifications - the examples given are all about getting the APNS token but there are (for whatever reason) no examples for getting the token for FCM.